# PHP was displaying properly, but is now displaying as text only

Tags: php

I'm brand new to PHP and I was working with it last night and earlier this morning through a YouTube video series. I did all of the installation last night and followed everything correctly. I went through the entire series with the PHP working and even up until now (1:15 CST).

However, when I went to the next video, implemented a change, and hit Refresh, the PHP file in my browser displays as code. So do all of my other PHP files. I didn't change anything in XAMPP nor any settings anywhere else. I can't find any help on it suddenly changing, the only thing I'm finding is it not displaying properly from the start.

What can I fix to again process my PHP code rather than displaying it?

Comment: This is caused by Apache not processing the file as a PHP script. Are you sure you have proper opening tag `<?php`?

Comment: Yes. This is happening with all of my past and current php files. All of the sudden, they are simply displaying the code. They were working before, but not now.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache and/or your server? Have you verified that nothing changed in the Apache configuration?

Comment: Then something must be wrong with your Apache configuration. The only other noobie mistake I can think of is that you are opening your PHP files directly with your web browser instead of going through HTTP (e.g. clicking open in your browser instead of pointing it to a URL like `localhost/myphpfile.php`)

Comment: can you paste the contents of one of your files? I guess it is possible that your text editor saved some weird characters that cause it to be interpreted as something other than php.

Comment: Maybe your Apache instance is sending it as `text/plain` for some strange reason.

Comment: Or, following @KaiQing's remark, the PHP file itself could be saved as plain text.

Comment: Tried restarting Apache, tried restarting XAMPP, same settings with Apache. Trying going through HTTP right now. I can't figure out how to paste code and make it readable for you guys, how do I do that? Sorry, I'm an idiot, I know...

Comment: might help to know what change you implemented right before it broke

Comment: @JamesWright PHP files are supposed to be saved as plain text.

Comment: @user1559665 we were all there once.  To have code formatted indent it 4 spaces.  It have code highlighted but kept inline then surround it with back ticks `\``. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I didn't implement any changes. I never went back to XAMPP, phpMyAdmin or anything outside of the text editor I was in and the window in which I was viewing the files. The PHP files were all saved as Unicode UTF-8. They were working earlier, but all of a sudden they're not. No changes in the path were made, nothing outside of the editor and the video page.

Comment: @Asad Maybe the file has a `text/plain` mime type which isn't recognised by the server. You're right, but here are the most suitable mime types for PHP: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-mimetype.htm

Comment: `<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            php
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // 3 Perform a query (ask a question)
            $equals = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CocaCola", $connect);
        ?>
        <?php
            // 4 Return the data
            while ( $column = mysql_fetch_array($equals)){
                echo $column[1] . " " . "<br>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    // 5 Close the connection
    mysql_close($connect);
?>`

Comment: Sorry, that's the only way I could figure out how to post it.

Comment: @JamesWright I'm not sure what you mean. A file by itself doesn't have a MIME type. Certain file extensions are associated with a particular MIME type by the server, and said type is specified in the headers by the server when serving up the file.

Comment: @Asad I've just been doing some reading and it turns out you can't trust everyone with whom you work :P Thank you for clearing things up.

Comment: @JamesWright No worries.

Answer (score 1):

I presume, that your php files are syntaxically correct, and you can run them with:

```
php file.php
```

Look at your httpd.conf:

1.Make sure, that you have something like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module "d:/bin/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "d:/bin/php"
```

Change the paths to your machine php installation dir. And check, that the library exists.

2.This one is responsible for processing index.php by default:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

3.Maps the given filename extensions onto the specified content type:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```